# Weird profile behavior on meta.gaming

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, user-profile

I've seen this happen several times since joining the private beta.

When I joined, Gaming pulled my profile from either Area 51 or Meta.SO, and thus had the name, "Dr. Gonzo." Both Gaming and meta.gaming used this name.

Now, I really only want that name on Meta.SO. On the other sites (aside from Area51, where I just didn't bother), I'm known by my birth name: "John Rudy."

No big deal, I just changed my name and profile on Gaming, and it was good. But meta.gaming, ever since, has occasionally switched between the profile associated with Gaming, and one of the profiles using "Dr. Gonzo." (I've noticed this also applies to the other profile fields, such as the "about me.") As I write this, it's using my Gaming profile. A short while ago, it was one of the Dr. Gonzo ones.

What's up?

Comment: I noticed this as well, although I actually prefer the name Grace Note (fitting for a gaming site), but my About Me section I would prefer to have my Meta SO one stay on Meta SO. Editing it on the parent site resulted in a delayed carryover, but since my latest change it's now an old version. The fact we can't edit our Meta Gaming profiles (which is itself bizarre) rather makes this distressing.

Comment: I assume the intended behaviour is for the meta profile to be the same as the main site, just like reputation, and that's why we cannot edit it. It's not currently replicating ok as you say

Comment: Meta tends to lag behind on things like reputation, I wouldn't be surprised if profile edits are also delayed.

Answer (score 1):

The association process copies account info from the site where you have the *highest* reputation.

For you that is meta. :)

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/14048?tab=accounts

Comment: A sadder fact has never been uttered ... However, the bug wasn't that it pulled Meta in the first place -- the bug was that for a period of several days, it kept *reverting* back to that profile, even after edits to my main Gaming profile, which seemed stable. (That said, it seems to have been stable now since the day after I posted this.)